# how to make hybrid app for iphone and android through phonegap

Tags: android, iphone, cordova

Actually i want to make an app which work on iphone as well as android. so i want to work with   phonegap tool. can it is possible to work ,i develop app one time and it will work iphone and android devices. any idea about it? send me some links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the starting point for Phonegap

[Phonegap API reference](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface)

It will create the resources for the platform that you choose. For hybrid application you need to write the native code and inject it into the resource.

For Android, see

[Android Webview JS Interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

Note: In iOS you can't able to call the native methods from JS methods directly. It might need some trick. Use Command Types for the communication.

Hope it helps for creating the Hybrid app.

Comment: Can you Suggest me links of hybrid Apps which is live at app store?

Comment: http://www.mobiloud.com/blog/2012/06/native-web-or-hybrid-apps/